# AJAX infinite scroll loads the same results multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I'm trying to write a function that loads the search results when user scrools to the end of the page. To do this I store a seach ID in the database along with the SQL query string and the index of the first  displayed element in the current iteration (after LIMIT keyword in the SQL query).

The problem is that when I scroll the page slowly it works alright. And when I scroll it fast it loads the same results twice I guess because AJAX function is fired twice. How can I fix this behavior?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>Result 1</div>
...
<div>Result N</div>
<div class="s-cache" data-cache="504" style="display:none" align="center"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight == $(document).height()) {
            var sCache = $('.s-cache');
            if (sCache.length) {
                //Show gif image
                sCache.show();
                var cache = sCache.data("cache");
                //Get search id
                $.ajax('selectproperty3.php', {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        "cache": cache
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        //Remove div with the last iteration id
                        $('.a-clear').remove();
                        $("#dynamic").append(response);
                    },
                    error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
                        $('#dynamic').html("Error: " + errorType + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

MYSQL table **searchcache** contains **id**, **search** and **ind** fields. For example id=504, search="SELECT * FROM properties WHERE id > 0", ind=12.

PHP:

```
$cache=(int)$_POST['cache'];
$num_imtems=12;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM searchcache WHERE id='$cache'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)==0) {
    echo "Error with the cache";
    exit();
} else {
    $sql_row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);
    $query = stripslashes($sql_row[1]);
    $index = $sql_row[2]+$num_imtems;
}

$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);
$subquery = $query." LIMIT ".$index.",".$num_imtems;
$subresult= mysql_query($subquery) or die (mysql_error());
$nextstep = $total > ($index+$num_imtems);

...Display search results...

if ($nextstep) {
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO searchcache (search,ind) VALUES ('$query','$index')";
    $insert_result = mysql_query($insert_query) or die (mysql_error());
    echo ("<div class=\"s-cache\" data-cache=\"".mysql_insert_id()."\" style=\"display:none\" align=\"center\"><img src=\"/images/ajax-loader.gif\"></div>");
}
```

Comment: You should debounce scroll event i guess, using a timeout

Comment: Add an empty div to the end, as a placeholder, with an attribute you can check for (i.e. have I already got a load going for this page #?), and append into the div on success. Note that paging values should be done client-side and passed in the request URL.

Comment: I'd try using a global flag in the javascript. For example window.LoadingResults = false;. Set to true right before your ajax call, false when ajax completes, and only start a new load if window.LoadingResults is currently false. So you'd surround the ajax call with an if( !window.LoadingResults ).